Where are all the Wheel of Time questions?
According to a hasty google, the word counts of the below popular fantasy series are as follows:



Series
Word count (main books only)




Harry Potter
1,084,170


LOTR
481,103


The Wheel of Time
4,410,036 (might include prequel not sure)



However, this SEDE query shows a starkly different set of numbers for total post length in the relevant tags:



Series
Total character count of tagged posts (main tags only)




Harry Potter harry-potter
5,911,532


LOTR the-lord-of-the-rings
1,746,108


The Wheel of Time the-wheel-of-time
250,597



HP gets 23x the post content with 0.25x the work content?!
So, where are all the Wheel of Time questions? So much and intricate content will surely generate many questions in readers - I seem to remember there were two active Usenet groups in the 1990s, while the series was still being released - so why aren't we seeing those questions here? One might say, the series is old enough that everything has already been discussed, so googling takes prospective askers to existing answers - but I offer you as counterpoint LOTR, which is even older and has been being discussed for even longer, yet still provides new content here.
What's going on?
My related and personal question is this - if I have a WOT question, for which google can find me an answer (but not a very good one), will I get dinged for 'lack of research' if I post it here? Doesn't seem to happen to HP askers, but you never know...

It's too long, hardly anyone has enough patience to read it.  The first book was a freaking tome, over 800 pages in paperback.  Nobody I knew was going to commit that much work to the first book of a new series (it was published as "book one") by an unknown author.  The first Potter book was a quarter the size, and a much lighter read.

@DavidW well.... I started my first (incomplete) read when I noticed book 7 at the top of weekly bestseller charts for multiiple weeks, when it was released in 1996, well before any kind of mass 'virality'. For me that doesn't sit well with 'no one's read it'. Random internet page tells me that aff the back of the TV adaptation, there are 5 million copies sold since the end of 2020. Doesn't say which specific books, admittedly.

I admit to exaggerating for effect, but the off-putting nature of the first book was real, and by the time the 6th book was out, over 5k paperback pages for a series not yet complete, nobody I knew was willing to jump in at that point.  Among all my friends I think there are 2 who have read the series and I don't know if they've finished it.  It may be a statistical fluke, but it just didn't take in my circles.

Of course, being cynical, I have another non-answer theory, and that's the more researched and fully fleshed-out a work's background is, the fewer questions arise.  As compared to another series whose author famously wrote by the seat of her pants, as it were, making stuff up as she went along...

Speaking personally, I'd (obviously?) be very happy to see more WoT questions here. Please post away.


So much and intricate content will surely generate many questions in readers

I don't know that number of questions is correlated to length of the body of text.
As an aside -- and this is just personal anecdote and not actual evidence of anything -- none of my friends who read scifi & fantasy have a particularly high opinion of WoT. In general, I don't know anyone directly (friend or otherwise) who is a fan or actively comments on it. The closest is a fan of Brandon Sanderson I know who commented on Sanderson continuing WoT (but he's actually a fan of Sanderson other works).

I think you missed a mammoth in the room by your word count analysis. The former two have been turned into films with immense success and popularity, which in turned also spurred the general popularity of the books and their universes. Looking down on "HP askers" won't change how the internet works, I'm afraid. ;-) From my limited exposure to WoT I also have the impression that the former two, yes even LotR, are also much more accessible in book form. You might be missing some great WoT questions, but I find the idea of comparing question word count to book word count rather...naive. ;-)

Maybe the WOT books are just so well-written that nobody needs to ask any questions about them? [He says, while trying to keep a straight face]

The first part of this post is opinion-based and not really answerable. We can't control what is popular to ask questions about on the site.
However to answer the second part of the post, where to me there is a legitimate question:

if I have a WOT question, for which google can find me an answer (but not a very good one), will I get dinged for 'lack of research' if I post it here?

In short, you should be okay.
We do have some standards for "research" but that bar is pretty low, not just on SFF but as a network wide topic. The community generally understands that not every is adept at using Google (or some other search engine of your own preference) . Heck, we don't even explicitly require you to have read/watched the work you want to ask questions about!
Now, I wouldn't recommend asking a large volume of questions that are relatively easily answered just because you feel like WOT is "represented enough" on the site as that may lead to backlash or be considered spamming.
Overall, if you have a question that you have found a partial answer from another site, explain that in question. Let a potential answerer know that you are not satisfied with commonly found results. Our users like a challenge and have a chance flex their brain to find good answers for works they like.

As an aside going back to the first part of the question, you may want to consider that the Harry Potter series is currently the best selling book series of all time at ~600 million sold with Harry Potter and Philosopher's Stone being the 4th best selling single book of all time. Comparatively the Wheel of Time series has ~100 million sold.

At 7 books, 600M copies of HP is around 80M full series (largely discounting the Jinxed Kid).  100M WoT books spread across 14 books is well under 10M series, so approximately an order of magnitude more people have purchased HP than WoT.  Without even accounting for the fact that a lot of my co-workers bought HP to read with/to their kids, which nobody's ever going to do with WoT.  (IOW, the disparity is a lot more than 6-fold.)

@DavidW - Not to mention the audiobooks also. They're far and away the top sellers on sites like Audible.

@Valorum JFC there are audiobooks?!  Of course there are, it simply never occurred to me.  OMG, the first book alone is 33 hours?!  It's like someone invented a brand new circle of Hell.

@DavidW - Therr are multiple versions with different readers, plus they've just announced that they're going to do a full cast audio version of all seven books exclusive on audible. Each one is going to be at least 10 hours long.

@DavidW Book six "The Lord of Chaos" is only six hours shorter than the expanded version of The Stand at 42 hours. It's the longest in the series, but not by much.

To add to Skooba's answer, there are other forces at play. Namely

WoT has not branched out a lot from print media. A good chunk of that is due to how poorly the rights were handled

Robert Jordan sold the film and TV rights to Wheel of Time back in the mid-2000s to Red Eagle Entertainment, a rights-handling company set up specifically to get the franchise expanded into TV, film comic books and video games. To say they failed spectacularly is an understatement. The Wheel of Time comic book was delayed multiple times and left incomplete. Red Eagle tried to crowdfund a mobile Wheel of Time game but asked for an obscene amount of money and then failed to publicise it anywhere, resulting in an unmitigated disaster. Red Eagle then won back some respect by commissioning Obsidian Entertainment, one of the best video games companies in the business, to work on a single-player RPG. However, they then failed to produce any money to fund the game. They somehow managed to sign a deal with Electronic Arts in which EA agreed to release the game but not fund it, one of the most inexplicably baffling failures of corporate dealing I've ever encountered.

Jordan himself was not happy with any of that

During the last few months of his life Robert Jordan had become very irritated with Red Eagle's handling of the Wheel of Time project and one of his very last blog posts was spent castigating them. Fan appreciation for Red Eagle's efforts cooled noticeably at that point.


There doesn't seem to be as much interest in it from the SFF community at large. I had a question about the Amazon TV series and I had to offer a bounty to get it answered. Ask a question about Tolkien and you're likely to get at least a few answers.


What drives SFF overall is fandom. People who know the stories well enough to tell you what's going on behind the scenes, and are still motivated to engage with those questions. I expect Amazon's efforts are driving some renewed interest, but there's no Lord of the Rings groundswell forthcoming either (reviews of Amazon's offerings are quite mixed).
